# How make link which rewrite to the same place and change 1 parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need make link which reqrite me to the same place witch one other route value.

**EXAMPLE**

**Route rule from `Global.asax`**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "News", // Route name
            "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/page-{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { lang = "pl", controller = "News", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

**page where I'm**

```
/pl/News/Index/page-6
```

**I want create link to**

```
/en/News/Index/page-6
```

so I want to change `lang` parameter. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your route to reflect something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("AnyLangRoute", "{lang}/{controller}/{action]/page-{page}", new { controller = "News", action = "Index" });
```

You want to remove the lang property from your parameter list, but keep it in the URL.

You will then want to use

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString()
```

to grab the {lang} value from the routeData. (NOTE: filterContext is a ControllerContext object).

So a URL of:

```
/en/News/Index/page-6
```

will have a "lang" value of: **en**

You can use that value to change the thread to the appropriate language using a Global Filter or something like that (see *ActionFilterAttribute* -- if you want more information on that).

Doing all this from memory, but hope it leads you in the right direction.